# How to make Set Filters box clickable as well as the filter icon

Tags: ag-grid

I'm using ag-grid (vanilla javascript) and would like to be able have the user click on the filter box (as well as the filter icon) to display the filter options.

Currently it is read only and can only be accessed by clicking the filter icon.

I cannot find any information in the documentation to allow this to happen and cannot think of a way to achieve this.

I've created a Plunker example which you can see here:
https://plnkr.co/edit/XQP8FFzSaaknRSMh2zdN?p=preview

```
    var columnDefs = [{
headerName: 'Athlete',
field: 'athlete',
width: 150,
filter: 'agSetColumnFilter',
filterParams: {
  cellHeight: 20,
  values: irishAthletes(),
  debounceMs: 1000
}
  }, {
    headerName: 'Country',
     field: 'country',
    width: 140,
    cellRenderer: 'countryCellRenderer',
keyCreator: countryKeyCreator,
filter: 'agSetColumnFilter',
filterParams: {
  selectAllOnMiniFilter: true
    }
  },
];
```

I would like a user to be able to click on the filter box (e.g. the box below 'Athlete') in the headers to display the relevant filter options.   As if they have clicked on the filter icons.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.